# What is the proper way to set an object to another object's value in ObjC?

Tags: objective-c, object

I am working in a `ViewController` class which uses a property called dates, its an `NSArray`, so in code I create it using:

```
self.dates = someFunctionThatReturnsAnNSArray;
```

That `self.dates` goes on to be used in a `UITableView` which is searchable.

I want to also take a copy of that `self.dates` array and use it to populate an `AppDelegate` property called globalArray.  So in my `ViewController` I import my `AppDelegate` and call its `sharedApplication` method and then do this:

```
AppDelegate *myDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
myDelegate.globalArray = self.dates;
```

My question is, is this the proper way to do this?  What about copy or retain?

```
myDelegate.globalArray = [self.dates copy];
myDelegate.globalArray = [self.dates retain];
```

Or what about `globalArray = arrayWithArray`?

```
myDelegate.globalArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.dates];
```

Which is the recommended format and why?

Comment: How have you declared your property ???

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, and what else may be done with the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your questions in order (including implied questions)

> What does self.dates = someFunctionThatReturnsAnNSArray do?

If the property is declared strong (ARC) or retain (non-ARC) then the generated setter -- which is what you're using with the dot notation -- will add to the retain count of the array so it won't be garbage collected.  Using the synthesized setter, you don't need any further memory management decoration on that statement.

> I want a copy kept as a global in my AppDelegate.  Is that a good idea?

"Copy" can be a tricky term in OO.  It might mean another, distinct collection of the same items which you'd get by saying `[array copy]`.  It might mean a new collection of copies of all the items.  You probably don't want either of these.  My guess is that you just want a pointer to the array available in a different scope.  This usually referred to as "assigning" the array.

In any case, the app delegate is probably not a good place to keep it.  App delegate is a singleton, so it's tempting to make it a dumping ground for globals that really should have a home in the app's model.

> Let's say I want another object to have that same array as a property, how do I do that?

That other object (like the app delegate, even though I disagree with that design) can also declare a property the same way as the original: nonatomic, strong or retain.  When you make the assignment using the dot operator, no further retaining is necessary.

> What about `someArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.dates]`?  How is that different?

It's just like copy.  It will create a new, distinct collection of the same items that are in self.dates.  My guess from your question is that you really just want to share the same data in different scopes.  For that, there's no need for copy or arrayWithArray.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using CD to create a new fetch in the other viewcontroller.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Hopefully you're not fetching the same data twice now.  Remember that it's just fine to "pass" that data to another VC by declaring a similar property on the other VC and assigning the array.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends somewhat on whether or not the array(s) in question are mutable or immutable and what kind of concurrency considerations are in play (will the arrays be accessed and/or modified by more than one thread).

You also appear to be using non-ARC syntax and may want to consider using ARC.

If the arrays are immutable, then retaining a copy of the array should be fine. If they are mutable (and you want to be able to track the two arrays separately) then you'll want to do a copy.

If the intention is really that there is one set of data (one, master array) that should be used globally, then you may just want to put some convenience methods on your view controller that access the master array (and avoid having two, separate pointers).

Comment: The self.dates array in the vc is gotten from CD.  CD is synced from a web service.  That property (self.dates) is used to populate a tableview so its actualy form is not mutable.  Each time it is created on app launch, the app syncs and creates an immutable array from the CD.